# Send variable/value to an other route after redirect Node js/express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to send a variable/value to the route that I am redirecting to. I have tested to set a header with that value. But it dosen't seem to work.

The first route (here I redirect the user):

```
res.writeHead(302, {
  'Authorization' : "VALUE HERE!!!", 
   "Location" : "/view/"
  });
res.end();
```

The destination:

```
router.get('/view', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.headers.authorization); <-- undefined
    res.render('login', {lang: "en", 
        title: "Title"});
});
```

The "req.headers.authorization" is undefined.

App.js

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
```

How can I send/pass a value/variable to the route where I am redirecting the user to? Without setting parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending headers to the user, not receiving them.  Its a 2 step process. I would use a query parameter instead:

```
res.writeHead(302, {      
  "Location" : "/view?access_token=abc"
});
```

While this is not as ideal as headers, things like OAuth specs do allow for it when headers are not possible and most auth libraries will look for the query param. Check with whatever library docs you are using for that.